# No imprime el valor del hook en el tag li

Tags: reactjs

estoy realizando una app en react, donde desde el componente base le paso un Hook a otro componente que tiene un tag  que luego este llama a otro componenete que recibe el hook y un tag li que muestra un valor de este hooke, pero el valor del hook en el li no se esta mostrando.

```
   const [tdos,setTodos] = useState([
        {id:1, task:"Tarea 1", completed:false},
        {id:2, task:"Tarea 2", completed:false}
    ]);
    return (
        <TodoList todos={tdos}/> 
    );
```

PRimer componente

```
 return(
        <ul>
            {todos.map(x=>{
               <TodoItems todos={x}/>
            })}
        </ul>
    )
```

Segundo componente

```
const {id,task,completed} = todos;
return(
    <li>{task}</li>
)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Comparte el segundo componente completo, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente te está faltando alguna llamada a **props** en algunos de los componentes.

Sugiero que uses la extensión de react para Chrome para chequear las props en cada uno de los componentes.