# Undefined al imprimir el valor de un hook en un componente hijo

Tags: javascript, reactjs

estoy intentando imprimir un hook que paso a un componente hijo , y si bien veo desde la extension de react que el componente tiene el hook, al imprimirlo imprime undefined.
En el componente hijo, hago destructuring e imprimo el valor

```
const { id, task, completed }= todos;
console.log(task)
return(
    <li>{task}</li>
)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Posible [pregunta repetida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/489215/no-imprime-el-valor-del-hook-en-el-tag-li), comparte el segundo componente completo, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Sugiero que compartas el código completo del segundo componente, porque solamente con esto es imposible identificar el problema.
Lo más probable es que tú error este en cómo obtener el valor de las props.

Como dato, estás tratando de imprimir un valor que te llega por props.
En este caso, dicho valor corresponde a un estado de un componente padre.
Estado que inicializaste usando un Hook (useState).

Te comento eso para que no mezcles los conceptos y te sea más sencillo leer la documentación, ya que hablas de imprimir un Hook, pero un Hook no es más que una función que en este caso te ayuda a inicializar un estado.